# Remove items in the first Lixtbox which is added in the second Listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitem, listbox-control

[image]

I am making a simple ftp app, when I click the browse button, the full path of the files will be added in the first ListBox. When I click on the Send Files button, it will execute and the full path will appear in the second ListBox. What I want to achieve is that, when a particular path is in the second ListBox, it will be removed in the first ListBox.

Here' what I have so far.

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         List<string> str = new List<string>();
         OpenFileDialog v1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        v1.Multiselect = true;
         if (v1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
             return;

         foreach (string s in v1.FileNames)
         {
             ////listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(s));
            listTransfer.Items.Add(Path.GetFullPath(s));
             str.Add(s);
         }
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendFiles();
    }





    private int SendFiles()
    {
        try
        {
            // Setup session options
            SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
            {
                Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
                HostName = "192.168.1.3",
                UserName = "Admin",
                Password = "foxtrotAlpha",
                PortNumber = 21
               // SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxxxxxxx...="
            };

            using (Session session = new Session())
            {
                // Connect
                session.Open(sessionOptions);

                // Upload files
                TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
                transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

                TransferOperationResult transferResult;
                //  transferResult = session.PutFiles(@"d:\upload\*", "/transfer/", false, transferOptions);

                foreach (var listBoxItem in listTransfer.Items)
                {
                    string item = listBoxItem.ToString();
                    string[] result = item.Split(',');
       

                    transferResult = session.PutFiles(@result[0], "/_transfer/", false, transferOptions);
             

                    // Throw on any error

                    transferResult.Check();

                    // Print results
                    foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
                    {
                        lblCompleted.Text = transfer.FileName.ToString();
                        listCompleted.Items.Add(lblCompleted.Text);
                    }
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception e )
        {       
            
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString(),"FTP",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return 1;
        }  
    }
```

Comment: You have stated a requirement, and shown a fair amount of code.  But you have not told us exactly what the problem is with this, nor what you have tried so far.  Please try to be more concise so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting

```
listTransfer.Remove(listBoxItem);
```

somewhere suitable, like above `//print results`..